# How does an appimage persist settings between launches?

Tags: appimage

[By popular request](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it/774520?noredirect=1#comment1634827_774520), I'm asking how do AppImages, which are [read-only and stay compressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it/774520#774520), store their settings.

Answer (score 12):

@muru's answer of course is correct and should be upvoted and accepted.

Let me add a few points for clarity:

- You can make the AppImage create the two directories all by itself by invoking it with the *`--appimage-portable-home`* and *`--appimage-portable-config`* parameters. This has to be done only once:

  ```
  ../some/path/to/my.AppImage --appimage-portable-home
  ../some/path/to/my.AppImage --appimage-portable-config
  ```

  This will create the respective (initially empty) directories:

  1. The AppImage will then think that `../some/path/to/my.AppImage.home/` is `$HOME`.
  2. The AppImage will also think that `../some/path/to/my.AppImage.config/` is `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.

     (BTW, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` very frequently defaults to `$HOME/.config`.)
- If you find above two parameters too difficult to remember, then memorize another one: `--appimage-help`. Using that will list and explain all the others which are available.
- Not every application makes use of `$HOME` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. In this case your newly created directories will remain empty. Otherwise they'll be populated by the AppImage's payload at runtime and when exiting to all settings it wants to remember.
- Many applications make use of only one of the two environment variables, `$HOME` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (and therefore of `my.AppImage.home/` resp. `my.AppImage.config/`), not both.
- *Some* applications may even get confused if *both* of the portable settings directories exist...
- If you re-name the `old.AppImage` to `new.AppImage`, the `old.AppImage.home/` and `old.AppImage.config/` directories immediately cease to work. You need to rename the two directories accordingly: `new.AppImage.home/` and `new.AppImage.config/`.
- If you rename *awesome.AppImage* to simply *awesome*, you have to rename the `awesome.AppImage.home/` directory too: namely, to `awesome.home/`.
- If you move the AppImage to a new location and want to keep the previously used config and home directories, you have to move these too.
- If you want to get rid of the old configuration and want to make the AppImage again use "standard" paths for `$HOME` for `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` then simply delete these directories again.
- If you want a new AppImage's payload to use the same settings as your system-installed version of the payload app, then you should:

  1. Create the relevant empty directory first;
  2. Locate the respective config directory of the system-installed app;
  3. Copy all content of that directory to the new empty one.

Comment: I wondered if they were being literal about using the "same name as the AppImage". Thanks for confirming. Do you know if AppImages have any support for `XDG_CACHE_HOME`?

Comment: When the AppImage startsup, it knows about its current name and absolute path. It then looks if the two named directories exist and have any interesting content for it to read. -- I don't think `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is currently supported. If `XDG_CACHE_HOME` isn't present the payload app is supposed to use `HOME/.cache`... Do you see a use case for where you want to make an AppImage use its own `XDG_CACHE_HOME` ? In this case, you should maybe submit an [issue on their GitHub tracker](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/issues)...

Comment: Nah, just wondering why there was support for `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` without the other XDG directories (cache, data).

Answer (score 10):

From [the AppImageKit README](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit#special-directories):

> #### Special directories
>
> Normally the application contained inside an AppImage will store its
>   configuration files wherever it normally stores them (most frequently
>   somewhere inside `$HOME`). If you invoke an AppImage built with a
>   recent version of AppImageKit and have one of these special
>   directories in place, then the configuration files will be stored
>   alongside the AppImage. This can be useful for portable use cases,
>   e.g., carrying an AppImage on a USB stick, along with its data.
>
> - If there is a directory with the same name as the AppImage plus `.home`, then `$HOME` will automatically be set to it before executing
>     the payload application
> - If there is a directory with the same name as the AppImage plus `.config`, then `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` will automatically be set to it
>     before executing the payload application

Answer (score 2):

in Ubuntu, the AppImage will store the settings by default in:

- `/home/user_name/.config/my_App_name`
- `/home/lwbaqueros/.my_App_name`

If you delete those folders, you will have a fresh version of your AppImage app