# How Can I Run An Appimage from Anywhere?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, kde

I'm interested in using an appimage program (I've read [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)), but without it installed, I can't find it in KDE's desktop search bar function. Is there a way to add it to the search bar, or make it discoverable via Konsole without having to navigate to a certain directory and performing `./program.appimage`?

Is that just the way appimages are supposed to work, or is there a way to make them behave more like regular programs?

Comment: Two things, add to path, and add launch icon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit, it mentions installation on Debian-based systems. It installs in these locations:

- `$HOME/Downloads` (or its localized equivalent, as determined by `XDG_USER_DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD` in `glib`)
- `$HOME/.local/bin`
- `$HOME/bin`
- `$HOME/Applications`
- `/Applications`
- `/isodevice/Applications`
- `/isofrom/Applications`
- `/run/archiso/img_dev/Applications`
- `/lib/live/mount/findiso/Applications`
- `/opt`
- `/usr/local/bin`

The last line there should make it run from any location, as I know that is in your path. So to check if that is the case run this command from the terminal:

```
which appimaged
```

Or simply

```
appimaged -v
```

The first will give the location of the program and the second will show the version installed, so in any case either should tell you if yours is setup as said in that link I provided.

I got this from that link, please take a look at it for more help:

> NOTE: It may be necessary to restart (or `xkill`) dash, nautilus, to recognize new directories that didn't exist prior to the first run of `appimaged`. Alternatively, it should be sufficient to log out of the session and log in again after having run `appimaged` once.
>
> If you have AppImageUpdate on your `$PATH`, then it can also do this neat trick:

[image]

- Image source:https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit

> Download AppImageUpdate from https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate/releases/tag/continuous and put on your `$PATH`:
>
> ```
> sudo mv "Downloads/AppImageUpdate-*.AppImage" /usr/local/bin/AppImageUpdate
> chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/AppImageUpdate
> ```

Comment: You can run an AppImage from *anywhere*, but the locations mentioned above are the locations that the optional appimaged daemon monitors for automatic integration into the system (menus, icons, MIME types, etc.)