# Run Instagram IGdm.appimage

Tags: appimage, instagram

I am trying to run IGdm.appimage (which I downloaded from http://igdm.me/).

I try to run it via terminal and it show me this error

```
adie@adie-X550DP:~/Desktop/Apps$ ./IGdm-2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage
module.js:545
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '/tmp/.mount_IGdm-29Pi51V/resources/electron.asar/browser/init.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:683:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:196:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:622:3
```

any solution for this? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://igdm.me and click on github on the top of the site then click on releases and download lastes release IGdm_2.5.1_amd64.deb (for x64 system) or IGdm_2.5.1_i386.deb (for x32 system) then install it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the file executable. before executing it.

#### Making a file executable

You can make the appImage executable as follows:

```
chmod a+x IGdm-2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage
```

#### Executing it

You can execute an appImage as follows:

```
./IGdm-2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage
```

For more info about appImage, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/774520/573344)