# How do I turn an appImage file an .exe

Tags: appimage

When I try the terminal I get this....

chmod: cannot access 'qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage': No such file or directory

The file is located in my downloads folder.

Comment: What is the path that prints when you drag the qTox-v1.16.3.x86_64.AppImage icon into the terminal?

Comment: .exe files is a windows thing, how is that related to Ubuntu / Linux ?

Comment: @SorenA I think the OP just wants to know how to execute/run an AppImage file.

Comment: Related: [How do I install qtox to Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1109764/504066)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path to the file when using the "chmod" command