# How to install geany in a usb drive?

Tags: usb, geany

I would like to have my own portable Geany installation to use on my uni computer. I saw that there is a Windows portable version of it but no linux. What would be the necessary steps to install Geany in a USB drive?

Comment: Geany 1.27 is available as an AppImage: https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/download_file?file_path=Geany-1.27.glibc2.15-x86_64.AppImage. For more on AppImages see https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it and https://www.maketecheasier.com/portable-apps-for-linux/.

Comment: What sort of linux, distro + version, are you planning on running the usb?