# How do you install appimages in multi-user environments

Tags: 19.04, appimage

I have been searching for months for information on how to use appimages in multi-user environments with little success.  I can tell it is meant for single users, but apparently it CAN be used in multi-user environments though I am still unable to figure out how.  See #10 under Objectives here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/774520/968864
Unfortunately, being an inexperienced linux user, I don't know to do this.  Can it be done and how can it be done?  I am trying out AppImageLauncher, but when I tried to change the directory to system folder, it would not allow it (presumably because that utility doesn't have root access).

Why does it matter?  Because I want all users to be able to use the appimages without having to copy it to each user's home directory.  I want it installed once, not 10 times.  Plus, when I backup home folders for all users, I don't want 10 copies of the appimage on the backup server.  This seems like a no-brainer, I don't understand why there is not more discussion about it.  Seriously, an application for linux that is not multi-user friendly?

Please help, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put appimages in /opt wich means optional. When you can't or you don't know where to install your apps you need to use this directory.

- Put all appimages files in a "appimages" directory.
- Open a terminal in that directory
- Type `sudo cp * /opt`

Users need to go in /opt or you can add launchers. https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files