# Install Stacer cleaner?

Tags: software-installation, cleanup

Does anyone knows the easy way to install Stacer cleaner ?

It has great interface as CCleaner and everything.

Any special way to install packages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring up new terminal window, run following command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oguzhaninan/stacer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install stacer
```

Or if you prefer [`.appimage`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it) format.

```
wget https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/releases/download/v1.1.0/Stacer-1.1.0-x64.AppImage
chmod a+x Stacer-1.1.0-x64.AppImage
./Stacer-1.1.0-x64.AppImage
```

<sub>http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/06/stacer-system-optimizer-cleaner-monitor-ubuntu/</sub>

Comment: Thanks .......the terminal helped a lot ..........I am just one week with Ubuntu aka Linux. I really like it a lot. Totally better than Mac and Windows 10, together.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to install Stacer is to install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

This will ensure a clean and correct installation.

Comment: Is this a snap? I don't see it in [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=stacer&searchon=names).

Comment: I checked an updated installation of Ubuntu 18.04. Stacer isn't available from the default repositories. And it isn't available as a snap. The version of Stacer seen in the bottom of your image matches that of the ppa already referenced in the [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1192459/248158).

Comment: @ChristianBearslyClark did that work fr you then?

Comment: YES !  The terminal worked !!! Thanks !