# I can not get the app Stacer to open after download to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

I have tried to download the app Stacer *1.1.0* amd64.deb and it appears in download file, but it does nothing after that. Also it appears to load 21 megabits of a 78 megabit file.

Comment: Have you looked at this reference? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192457/install-stacer-cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This application with this version is [too new](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/stacer) for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS package base. It will not install because of dependencies.

You have to follow [official readme](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/) and add [special repository (PPA)](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoguzhaninan/+archive/ubuntu/stacer?field.series_filter=xenial) with this application to the system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oguzhaninan/stacer -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install stacer -y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download appimage directly and use it.
https://appimage.github.io/Stacer/

Comment: I downloaded and it will not open or run. It creates an invalid coding error.

Comment: Since you are using ubuntu 16 which is old, stacer might not work. Give a try with old versions of stacer from the repository : https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer/releases