# Openshot can't use Blender in Ubuntu Studio 20

Tags: blender, openshot

Just installed Ubuntu Studio 20
Tried animated title which needs access to Blender (version at least 2.78, installed is 2.82a)

The default Blender command path is blender, also tried /usr/bin/blender

Error message:  No frame was found in the output from Blender

Worked fine in Studio 18

Comment: Same. Downloaded Blender 2.83.0 - unzipped. Opened OpenShot (2.4.3) preferences, updated Blender path to unzipped executable. Tried both: `/home/YOURname/Downloads/blender-2.83.0-linux64/blender` `~/Downloads/blender-2.83.0-linux64/blender` Neither worked.

Comment: The version of Blender is too new: see this wiki page: https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/wiki/How-to-troubleshoot-errors-with-animated-titles . No worked solution yet for me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is best solved by just downloading and installing the AppImage: https://www.openshot.org/download/

Read here for how to install an AppImage file: [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)

Answer (score 0):

This is a old post but I have to provide the actual fix as this problem transcends versions. You need to point to the render process and not the application itself ~/Downloads/blender-2.83.0-linux64/blender-softwaregl