# How to install/run an AppImage on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, appimage

I installed an AppImage on my laptop with Lubuntu 18.04.5 but I can't get it to run. When I click on the "properties" tab of the AppImage, I can't see the setting that says "Allow executing files as program" so I'm not sure what I should do. If anyone is wondering, the AppImage I am trying to install is Ripcord, a rewritten version of discord meant for 32-bit systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)

Answer (score 3):

To run an AppImage you need to first give executing permissions then you run it, I do not know where to give the permissions in Lubuntu but I know how to do them in the terminal

```
sudo chmod +x /path/to/file.AppImage
```

then you can run by clicking the file on the file manager or by executing it on the terminal