# Appimage won't run on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, appimage

I ran so many of these options and not a single one helped. I just can't seem to be able to run AppImages on Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry Pi 4 8 GB. Specifically, I want to run AppImages from Trezor wallet and Ledger wallet, but I even tried some random AppImages from [appimage.org](https://appimage.org/).

Nothing happens if I run the AppImages; sometimes they would just give me an error. It's like my Ubuntu just doesn't have the filesystem to be able to run AppImages.

I don't know what app I need to install at this point to get AppImages to run. I even went to the official AppImage website ([appimage.org](https://appimage.org/)) and all I could find there was these commands which do not work:

```
chmod a+x exampleName.AppImage
./exampleName.AppImage
```

- Relevant post: [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it)

Comment: Hmmm. I downloaded and ran an AppImage yesterday by doing exactly the steps that seem to not work for you. How curious

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Desktop environment? Run conditions? What is CPU architecture of system? What is CPU architecture of AppImage?

Comment: You said you tried:
"chmod a+x exampleName.AppImage./exampleName.AppImage" Did you navigate to the same directory that your .AppImage was in? (using the cd command.)
Also, did you use sudo?
"*sudo* chmod a+x exampleName.AppImage./exampleName.AppImage

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way in a terminal:

```
./exampleName.AppImage --disable-gpu --no-sandbox
```

where `exampleName.AppImage` is the name of the AppImage app you want to run.

Most of the time problems with AppImages are GPU's fault. Also, after installing Ubuntu 22.04, almost all my AppImages are crashing without this command.

Comment: This indeed works for Ubuntu 22.04, where double-clicking an AppImage or running it in a terminal using only its name don't work.

Answer (score 0):

AppImage requires the [`fuse3` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/fuse3), which may not be installed by default. Install it and retry.

Comment: This might be true but I'm unable to run neovim on the raspi even after installing fuse3, probably because it's for x64.

Answer (score -2):

Presuming you downloaded the image to `~/Downloads`, then open your Terminal, and do this:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo chmod 750 ./example.appimage
./example.appimage
```

Make sure you are in the correct working directory and try `sudo` in case you lack permissions to the directory for some odd reason.  Other than that, should work fine.

Comment: One should be very careful when using `sudo`. In your second command, the use of `sudo` is superfluous, since you are in a directory inside your `~`, for which you should already have permissions to change things, so `chmod 750 ./example.appimage` should be enough. Also, suggesting to blindly run `sudo` to gain permissions for a directory is wrong and I guess that this is the reason your answer is downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - very helpful.