# AppImage files are not executing in Ubuntu Guest OS

Tags: 22.04, appimage

I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Guest OS on my Windows 10 using VirtualBox 6.1.36. I have downloaded various appimage files and ticked the **Allow executing file as program** in its Properties option, but nothing happens when I click "Run". How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an "AppImage"? How do I install it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it) Please read the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04, you need to install the package `libfuse2`, which is not anymore installed by default in Ubuntu 22.04. AppImages with time will (need to) update to the newer version of `libfuse`.