# How to install Obsidian 1.0.3 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, software-center, snap, flatpak

I am currently referring to the **Obsidian note taking app**. (see [www.obsidian.md](https://obsidian.md)).

The Obsidian AppImage did not work for me. Ubuntu Software Center just could not open it.
Same goes for the Snap or Flatpak package.

Anything I did wrong besides just trying to open the files and launching die Ubuntu Software Center?

Edit: If there are suggestions to make it work with snap, they are welcome. If I find the answer to that option as well I will post it here.

Software version and Ubuntu version are as mentioned in the title.

Comment: "*The Obsidian AppImage did not work for me*" is vague. Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it . If it fails, tell us exactly which step failed and provide complete output.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just doubleclicked the file and nothing happened. That permissions have to be changed was unknown to me and I just needed to get the software running on my system. With the next chance I will test the Appimage again.

Comment: Used Appimage for a different software and worked like a charm. Wish I knew it before and  (from a user perspective) that more packages used the format.

Comment: Keep in mind that AppImages don't get updates or security patches. When you install an AppImage, that becomes your responsibility.

Comment: Is it OK if we make this question more general to all Ubuntu versions, and not just 22.04?

Answer (score 7):

There is a Snap version of Obsidian now:

[image: Get it from the Snap Store]

If you prefer using the command line, you can run this command:

```
sudo snap install obsidian --classic
```

This snap version of Obsidian is not sandboxed, which is why the `--classic` flag needs to be passed.

Comment: This did not work for me, the snap version of the app will not start and no error is reported

Comment: @cjohansson Obsidian is now in the Snap Store, it may work for you now.

Answer (score 6):

I dived into the Terminal and installed Flatpak.

1. Install flatpak `sudo apt install flatpak`
2. Check version to make sure it is installed `flatpak --version`
3. Enable Flathub to search apps from command line `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`
4. Search is done by `flatpak search <app_name>`
5. Check the Application ID and run the installation with the application ID. I found it easier than choosing the right name.
   `flatpak install <app-id>`

Then I went on to look for Obsidian from Flathub.

1. Search Obsidian: `flatpak search obsidian`
2. Look for *md.obsidian.Obsidian* application ID
   `flatpak install md.obsidian.Obsidian`

After system restart Obsidian showed up in the application launcher.

DONE.

NOTE: Obsidian only works with locally available files. e.g. GoogleDrive via **Gnome Online Accounts** only offers access to the cloud service without actually downloading the files locally.

Answer (score 0):

use `chmod +x "filename.appimage"` to get it executable first mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I am still using ubuntu 20.04 and installed obsidian through snap and it stared crashing this is how I manually updated it

```
$ sudo snap download obsidian
Fetching snap "obsidian"
Fetching assertions for "obsidian"
Install the snap with:
   snap ack obsidian_22.assert
   snap install obsidian_22.snap
sudo snap install --dangerous --classic obsidian_22.snap
obsidian 1.5.3 installed
```

That's how I recovered it back. Sharing maybe it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Obsidian provides `deb` package now from their github repo.

Here is a link to [obsidian_1.5.8_amd64.deb](https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-releases/releases/download/v1.5.8/obsidian_1.5.8_amd64.deb)

(Make sure you download the latest version if you are reading this answer at a later date)