Viber doesnt work for Ubuntu 24.04?
I just started using Linux with Ubuntu 24.04.
Viber is my choice of messsaging with my family back home, and I had it my Windows PC. I tried to install it in Ubuntu 24.04 via the AppCenter but it wont get past through the window where its asking for my mobile number.
I tried other methods of installing as well but the installation will show some errors.
Could someone please help if this is a known issue and what should I do?
Thanks,

Try using the Appimage from https://www.viber.com/en/download/ how to install app image https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it

thanks! this worked! had to add fuse first before I could run the appImage but it worked!

Download Viber .AppImage file
Download the latest Viber from https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.AppImage
mkdir -p ~/Applications
wget -O ~/Applications/viber.AppImage https://download.cdn.viber.com/desktop/Linux/viber.AppImage
chmod +x ~/Applications/viber.AppImage

To run AppImages you may need to install libfuse
sudo apt install libfuse2t64

Create .desktop launcher
You can do this manually or use AppImageLauncher.
For Ubuntu 24.04 the maintainer of AppImageLauncher recommends installing the .deb from the continuous build https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/tag/continuous.
Replace appimagelauncher_2.2.0-gha111.d9d4c73+bionic_amd64.deb with what is the latest version for you.
# Download the pre-compiled .deb build
wget -O appimagelauncher.deb https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/download/continuous/appimagelauncher_2.2.0-gha111.d9d4c73+bionic_amd64.deb

# Install the .deb build
sudo dpkg -i appimagelauncher.deb

# Fix dependancy problems if you get errors about missing libraries
sudo apt --fix-broken install -y

# May also be needed
sudo systemctl restart systemd-binfmt

# Delete the installation file
rm appimagelauncher.deb

Start the viber.AppImage file and when the AppImageLauncher pops up, click on Integrate and Run. This will automatically create the required .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications.

Associate running instance with the .desktop launcher
You need to add the StartupWMClass to the .desktop file of the launcher of the AppImage. Otherwise your running instance will not get associated with the .desktop launcher.
The .desktop files are located at ~/.local/share/applications. The file you are looking for should look somethinge like this: appimagekit_1b8ef8b1293fa7f66ca83453aa2da417-Viber.desktop. Open it and add the following new line after Type=Application:
StartupWMClass=Viber


Unpacking appimagelauncher (2.2.0-gha111~d9d4c73+bionic) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of appimagelauncher:
appimagelauncher depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.

@CodeBy This should fix your problem: sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
